# Login form not working on Ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, authentication

I've recently come across a strange problem, I have a simple `html` login form which works fine on a Phone and Desktop however doesn't work on iPad instead it just refreshes the page. At first I thought removing `'#'` from `href=""` and adding `'javascript:;'` would work however it's done nothing.

Form:

```
<form action="#" id="frmSignIn" method="post" name="frmSignIn">
    <p>
        <label class="uname" data-icon="u" for="username">Email Address:</label>
        <input class="formInput" maxlength="80" name="email" onkeydown="fnTrapKD('btnLgn', event);" style="width:150px;" value="">   
    </p>
    <p>
        <label class="pword" data-icon="u" for="password">Password:</label>
        <input class="formInput" name="password" onkeydown="fnTrapKD('btnLgn', event);" style="width:150px;" type="password"> 
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="formCheckBox" name="cookie" type="checkbox" value="1"> &nbsp; Remember me
    </p>
    <input name="action" type="hidden" value="">
    <input id="loginbutton" name="loginbutton" type="hidden" value="">
    <p>
        <span class="floatr orange medium awesome">
            <a href="javascript:;" id="btnLgn" name="btnLgn" onclick="document.getElementById('loginbutton').value='loginbutton'; document.forms.frmSignIn.submit();" title="Login">Login</a>
        </span>
    </p>
    <div class="fpassword">
        <a href="#">Forgotten your password?</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: where is the form processed after submittng ?

Answer (score 1):

you need to specifiy the action page in the form tag

```
<form action="thispage.php" method="post" name="frmSignIn" id="frmSignIn">
```